Rails 7 actiontext embedded images
Using trix 2.1.2, Rails 7.1.3.4,  I'm able to create a message with an embedded image (using google for active storage) and it displays when I first create the message and also when I "show" the message, but when I go back to edit the message again it's not showing up.  I get the figure tag but no image tag nested inside the figure. Has anyone else had this issue?
I've updated to the latest trix, etc.

Any errors in your logs?
